# Front Facing Camera showing preview but not taking picture

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I started with the [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) code and everything is working fine with the Rear camera.

Then I tried to allow taking picture with the front facing one on some conditions so I did something like this :

```
Integer facing;
switch (mPictureType) {
    case REAR:
        facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
        if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    case FRONT:
        facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
        if (facing != null && ( facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK || facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL )) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
}
```

But now the picture can't be taken with the front camera, and still the preview is displayed correctly.

Do you have any idea of what I might have done wrong ?

Comment: which device do you use for testing this?

Comment: I use a `Sony Xperia Z3 Compact`